# setting up github ssh on windows 7 machine

Tags: git, ssh, github

I just installed git on my windows machine using [git's how to guide](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/), but I am having a problem.

When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` step I am getting this error:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

here is a longer trace that I got by running `ssh -vvv git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bmehanni/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /c/Users/bmehanni/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bmehanni/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bmehanni/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Thanks

Comment: This should probably go on serverfault instead of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but never found a way to solve it.

The workaround was to use https instead of ssh.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the type of your id_rsa key is wrong

```
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type
```

ssh is trying to infer the type from the key file name. When you generate the key, you need to specify the type with `-t rsa` flag.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Also, accept the default values for the file name of your private key `id_rsa` and your public key `id_rsa.pub`, otherwise you would need to add a configuration for github in `~/.ssh/config` file specifying the private key to use for that specific host.

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile C:/Users/youruser/.ssh/someotherkeyname
```

Comment: that's what I have been trying because that is what github specify in their guide but to no avail, for now I just switched to https instead of ssh.

Comment: @ManuelM. could you try adding the key to the authentication agent, with `ssh-add /path/to/key`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with your ssh key, so I'm guessing something went wrong while you were running ssh-keygen.  Try re-running that step

Comment: Yeah, try doing the steps again. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I don't believe I am behind a proxy. I tried regenerating the id_rsa.pub but I am getting the same error again. I don't have a config file, or a known_hosts file, do I need them?