# Trying to re-install github, get Permission denied (public key)

Tags: github

My computer crashed and I'm trying to re-install GitHub.

I follow the [step by step instructions](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/): Created a rsa key, added it to GitHub then typed in

> $ ssh -T git@github.com

I get "access denied". I'm assuming something is missing

Comment: Ted, **GitHub** _is a web-based hosting service for software development projects that use the Git revision control system_. You are asking a question about how to install **Git**, which is a software used by GitHub, or how to access **GitHub**, which is a place from which Git can pull files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on windows? if so, you probably will end up switching to https instead of ssh, I couldn't get ssh to work following the example either [Here is my question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480219/setting-up-github-ssh-on-windows-7-machine)

if you never used https to connect before, here is the syntax

```
git clone git@github.com:bmehanni/hammock.git
```